# maximum size of email message

Tags: .net, email

We have developed the .net application we got the following exception

"The message could not be send to the smtp server. The transport error code was 0x800ccc62. The server response was 500 line limit exceeded

how to resolve the problem?

Comment: This seems to be a server limitation, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 4):

Send smaller messages.